# How to create a paywall using the Etherscan API in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, string, blockchain, ethereum

I'm trying to make a simple paywall which uses Etherscan API to retrieve transactions from an address (currently set to my wallet on the rinkby testnetwork) and gather all the "from" addresses (the addresses of all people who have sent money to the address in a very basic way).

I managed to create a string of all the senders. Next part I need to check this list of addresses against an address entered on the webpage - if the address entered matches an address on the string of senders addresses `var x` - the pay wall is lifted.

This is where I'm stuck.

Both input from the input box and the x variable are stings, as shown in the console. However I cant get an input value to be matched to x.

I tried matching and using `indexOf`, which will work if you have entered the address manually as part of the code (shown in code) but it won't work with a value from the input box. I tried a similar thing with `indexOf`, same problem.

Another issue I run into if I can get this to work is that i need there to be an exact match for a full address only, as partial matches can still be found in x with the methods I've tried.

I essentially need the sender address to act as a password/key to access whatever is behind the paywall.

I'm sure there are lots of better ways of doing this, please help if you can.

```
<?php 
$url = "http://api-rinkeby.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0x445b5f277D463122a2Aaeac8B77d8f60865156Dc&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken";
$fgc = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
$fgc2 = $fgc["result"];

?>
<html>
all senders
<div id="demo"> </div>
matched in all senders list
<div id="demo2"></div>

<input type="text" id="ethadd" onChange="ethConvert()"; onKeyUp="ethConvert()"; value="enter address";  > enter address to check if payment has been sent

<script>
var myObj, i, x = "", lenght, allSenders; 
var amount = document.getElementById("ethadd").value
var amount2 = toString(amount);

myObj = <?php echo json_encode($fgc2);?>;

for (i in myObj) {
    x += myObj[i].from + "<br>" ;
}

//both iput from the iput box and the x variable are stings however I cant get an input value to be matched to x
console.log(typeof x);
console.log(typeof amount);

var n = x.indexOf(amount);

//tried using this to match an address put in the input box to part of the string - it works if you have enter the address
//manually like this but wont work with a value fromt the input box tried a similar thing with indexOf, same problem - wont work with
//anything from the input box 
var string = x;
var expr = /0x445b5f277d463122a2aaeac8b77d8f60865156dc/

document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = string.match(expr);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually got the indexOf to work  with 
function ethConvert() {
 n = x.indexOf(document.getElementById("ethadd").value)
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = n;
}
still having the other problems.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the structure of `$fgc`. Also where is `ethConvert` defined?

Comment: here is $fgc: http://api-rinkeby.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0x445b5f277D463122a2Aaeac8B77d8f60865156Dc&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken  
the bit I need is an array inside "results", then from each index of the array the "from" address.

I've managed to solve the problems I was having with indexOf and match, now the problem is making sure that only an exact match of the full address can be made from data entered into the input box. How can I constrain indexOf and match to finding full address matches only?

Answer (score 0):

Some of your markup is wrong, which may be causing some issues. I don't see `ethConvert` defined anywhere, so this is probably another reason why you aren't seeing the desired behavior on change/keyup events. This is a stripped down and untested example w/ logic of collecting the 'from' addresses moved to PHP instead of JS.

Should note, this isn't secure so don't rely on it for anything important.

```
<?php 
    $apiKey       = '';
    $url          = "http://api-rinkeby.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0x445b5f277D463122a2Aaeac8B77d8f60865156Dc&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey={$apiKey}";
    $transactions = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
    $addresses    = [];

    if (isset($transactions['result'])) {
        foreach ($transactions['result'] as $transaction) {
            $addresses[] = $transaction['from'];
        }
        // in php5.5+, this foreach could be replaced with
        // $addresses = array_column($transactions['result'], 'from');
    }
?>
<html>
    enter address to check if payment has been sent

    <input type="text" id="eth_address" onchange="checkAddress()" value="enter address" />
    <!-- you had some markup mistakes on this input, specifically the ; chars -->

    <script>
        var addresses = <?php echo json_encode($addresses); ?>;

        function isValid() {
            return addresses.indexOf(document.getElementById('eth_address').value) > -1;
        }

        function checkAddress() {
            if (isValid()) {
                alert('lift paywall');
            }
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, appreciate the help. I updated the code a bit after posting which is why you couldn't see it, apologies for the confusion. I'll give what you've suggested a try, looks a lot neater. I know it's not secure - the problem being that all the data on blockchain is public anyway so that in all honesty if people were that desperate to not pay they could just scan for transactions on etherscan and just copy and paste the address from there, so i don't see the point of making it secure, more of pay what you want donation thing where the content is free anyway, what do you think?

Comment: thanks again, that works great, lot better than what i came up with haha

Comment: Yep, good point on the security, glad it's been considered! Glad I could help. Btw it's not better, it's pretty much exactly what you came up with though, just with some slight adjustments. Good luck w/ the project.